# How to query on two arrays at the same time in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, document

I have the following documents, where each document has fields `values` and `dates`, which are arrays. These arrays always have the same size in each document, meaning each value in `dates` corresponds to a value in `values`:

```
[
  {
    _id: "Stock1",
    values: [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ],
    dates: [
      ISODate("2000-01-01"),
      ISODate("2010-01-01"),
      ISODate("2020-01-01")
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "Stock2",
    values: [
      4,
      5,
    ],
    dates: [
      ISODate("2000-01-01"),
      ISODate("2010-01-01")
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "Stock3",
    values: [
      7,
      8,
      9
    ],
    dates: [
      ISODate("2000-01-01"),
      ISODate("2010-01-01"),
      ISODate("2020-01-01")
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to query my documents such that I obtain `values` between `dates` "2010-01-01" and `dates` "2020-01-01" (included) for "Stock1" and "Stock3" only, i.e. I would like to end up with:

```
[
  {
    _id: "Stock1",
    values: [
      2,
      3
    ],
    dates: [
      ISODate("2010-01-01"),
      ISODate("2020-01-01")
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "Stock3",
    values: [
      8,
      9
    ],
    dates: [
      ISODate("2010-01-01"),
      ISODate("2020-01-01")
    ]
  }
]
```

For the moment, I am doing the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: {
        $in: [
          "Stock1",
          "Stock3"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$dates",
      includeArrayIndex: "date_index"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      dates: {
        $gte: ISODate("2010-01-01"),
        $lte: ISODate("2020-01-01")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$values",
      includeArrayIndex: "value_index"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$date_index",
          "$value_index"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      date_index: 0,
      value_index: 0
    }
  }
])
```

But I am not quite there yet. Also, the pipeline looks long and sub-optimal. Are there better ways to do this? Finally, I am first using `unwind` on `dates`, then filtering before using `unwind` again on `values`: This is to avoid a number of documents in the pipeline being too big as the array `dates` and `values` can be potentially huge.

Any help would appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query

- match the to keep only `"Stock1","Stock3"`
- filter on indexes of dates `(range (size "$dates"))`, to get only the indexes of elements with date in the range `[2010-2020]`
- 2 map to get those filtered indexes from `dates` and `values`

*we could do all in like 1 reduce but it would be nested and more complicated code, also `$concatArrays` is slow and its not good idea to reduce array to array.The bellow is simpler and can work even for very big arrays.

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6233d039f7e3c64c6511e143)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"_id": { "$in": ["Stock1","Stock3"]}}}
 {"$set": 
    {"indexes": 
      {"$filter": 
        {"input": {"$range": [0, {"$size": "$dates"}]},
          "cond": 
          {"$and": 
            [{"$gte": 
                [{"$arrayElemAt": ["$dates", "$$this"]},
                  ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00Z")]},
              {"$lte": 
                [{"$arrayElemAt": ["$dates", "$$this"]},
                  ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z")]}]}}}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"dates": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": "$indexes",
          "in": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$dates", "$$this"]}}}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"values": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": "$indexes",
          "in": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$values", "$$this"]}}}}},
  {"$unset": ["indexes"]}])
```